# Sound Multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, background, audio, dos

I want to play sound while a game is running. I know how to play sound and run the game, but I can't do them at the same time. The DOS game pauses while the sound is playing. Here is the cpp code for the sound:

```
void watersplashsound()
{PlaySound(TEXT("waterSPLASH.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);}
```

I don't know if it is a situation where you have to multithread. I think I know what multithreading is but I'm not sure.

Comment: Which library or API are you using? (Where PlaySound is?)

Answer (score 3):

`Playsound` needs another flag to not run synchronously. Call it like this:

```
void watersplashsound()
{
  PlaySound(TEXT("waterSPLASH.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
}
```

Notice that i have no idea how to stop the sound until it finishes.

Comment: @someguy If this answer was the one that helped you, click the check mark next to it to confirm that this was the most useful answer.

Comment: To stop an asynchronously playing sound: PlaySound(NULL, 0, 0);

Comment: I will use the wait function with that and try to set that up

Comment: Nvm that doesn't play the sound while the game is going

Comment: @someguy, you tried with SND_ASYNC?  Not SND_SYNC, but with the "A".